# how to return a nested entity model from odata services

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm implementing like [ODataServiceSample](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/ODataServiceSample/ReadMe.txt).

It say, you can query a nested entity model like as

```
public class ProductFamily
{
    public ProductFamily()
    {
        Products = new List<Product>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

but you can query partial, first request for main class

```
Container ctx = new Container();
foreach (var productFamily in ctx.ProductFamilies)
    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}-{1}: {2}", productFamily.ID, productFamily.Name, productFamily.Description);
```

second request for sub class

```
private static void Get_ProductFamily_Products()
    {
        Container ctx = new Container();
        var query = ctx.ProductFamilies.Where(p => p.ID == 3).SelectMany(p => p.Products);
        foreach (var product in query)
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}-{1}", product.ID, product.Name);
    }
```

How to select all data in one query(request)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand related entities, add `Expand` to your query. In your case it might be something like this:

```
Container ctx = new Container();
foreach (var productFamily in ctx.ProductFamilies.Expand("Products"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}-{1}: {2}", 
        productFamily.ID, productFamily.Name, productFamily.Description);
    foreach (var product in productFamily.Products)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t\t{0}-{1}", 
            product.ID, product.Name);
    }
}
```